# Get height of a div and add the value for another div

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, height

I want to get the height of a div and then to add that value as "top" or "margin-top" to another div. 
The first div has dynamical height and at its bottom I want to place another div that contains a link and a fb like button.
The html code looks like this:

```
...
<div id="testnew">content</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="left">content</td>
<td id="right">
    <div id="test">content</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
...
```

So #testnew is the second div with absolute positioning and right:0;, and #test is the first div with dynamical height.

I found this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704242/get-the-height-of-top-div-and-place-that-value-as-a-top-padding-of-another-div)

changed it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socialNetcss = $("#test").height();
$("#testnew").css({ top: socialNetcss});
</script>
```

but it didn't work.

I'm a newbie in jQuery/Javascript but I really want to do this thing. Thanks in advance!

PS: I know I can directly place the second div at the firsts bottom but then I have a problem with the fb like button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example here:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srfEn/1/)

```
<div id="first">first<br />first <br />first </div>
<div id="second"></div>​

$(document).ready(function () {
var height= $("#first").height();

$("#second").css({marginTop: height});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "top" won't work unless your div #testnew has position style property set to absolute or relative

Try "margin-top" instead of "top" in above code

Comment: I've said that the #testnew div has absolute positioning. Now the problem is solved! Thanks.